# XQuery how to make a similarity matrix?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Let us assume that we have **n** records. I want to calculate the similarity between each record and all other records. I want to make a similarity matrix. I'm new to XQuery but I'm trying my best.  I attached a screen shot of how the similarity between a pair of records must look like. [image: similarity between 2 records]

It is a csv string. I used the following for loops to produce this sample:

```
for $item1 at $index in /rec:Record 
let $records:= /rec:Record 
for $item2 in $records[$index + 1]

(: here I call the similarity functions :)

return 
(: csv output :)
```

I need to edit the for loops to produce a similarity matrix between every pair of records in the data set. How to do that??

**NOTE**: the similarity functions are ready, my problem is **NOT** in calculating the similarity itself.

Comment: How about `$records[position() > $index]`? It would be easier to help if you would provide a more complete and running code sample, with received versus expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Added CSV output as text node to end:

Consider the power of maps in MarkLogic.

Sample of representing a matrix in ML follows. I hooked in 2 things as well: A function as a place holder for your formula (including passing in your original sequence in case you need it all for analysis) as well as a little function to show how to access maps of maps.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:csv($matrix){
  let $nl := "&#10;"
  return text{ 
    for $x in map:keys($matrix)
      let $row := map:get($matrix, $x)
      order by xs:int($x)
      return fn:string-join(for $y in map:keys($row)
        order by xs:int($y)
        return xs:string(map:get($row, $y))
      , ",") || $nl 
  }
};

declare function local:my-formula($x, $y, $seq){
let $foo := "do something"
return "your-formula for " || xs:string($x) || " and " || xs:string($y)
};

declare function local:pretty($matrix){
  <matrix>
  {
    for $x in map:keys($matrix)
      order by xs:int($x)
    return <row>
    {
    let $row := map:get($matrix, $x)
     for $y in map:keys($row)
        order by xs:int($y)
            return <cell x="{$x}" y="{$y}">{map:get($row, $y)}</cell>

    }
    </row>


  }
 </matrix> 
};

let $matrix := map:map()
let $numbers := "1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8"
let $seq := fn:tokenize($numbers, ",")

let $_ := for $x in $seq
    let $map := map:map()
    let $_ := for $y in $seq
       return  map:put($map, $y, local:my-formula($x, $y, $seq))
    return map:put($matrix, $x, $map)

return local:pretty($matrix)
```

You could just dump out the map of maps ($matrix). However, the local:pretty function returns a format for you to easily see the construction of the map of maps:

```
<matrix>
  <row>
    <cell x="1" y="1">your-formula for 1 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="2">your-formula for 1 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="3">your-formula for 1 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="4">your-formula for 1 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="5">your-formula for 1 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="6">your-formula for 1 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="7">your-formula for 1 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="1" y="8">your-formula for 1 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="2" y="1">your-formula for 2 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="2">your-formula for 2 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="3">your-formula for 2 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="4">your-formula for 2 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="5">your-formula for 2 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="6">your-formula for 2 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="7">your-formula for 2 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="2" y="8">your-formula for 2 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="3" y="1">your-formula for 3 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="2">your-formula for 3 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="3">your-formula for 3 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="4">your-formula for 3 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="5">your-formula for 3 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="6">your-formula for 3 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="7">your-formula for 3 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="3" y="8">your-formula for 3 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="4" y="1">your-formula for 4 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="2">your-formula for 4 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="3">your-formula for 4 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="4">your-formula for 4 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="5">your-formula for 4 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="6">your-formula for 4 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="7">your-formula for 4 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="4" y="8">your-formula for 4 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="5" y="1">your-formula for 5 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="2">your-formula for 5 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="3">your-formula for 5 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="4">your-formula for 5 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="5">your-formula for 5 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="6">your-formula for 5 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="7">your-formula for 5 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="5" y="8">your-formula for 5 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="6" y="1">your-formula for 6 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="2">your-formula for 6 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="3">your-formula for 6 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="4">your-formula for 6 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="5">your-formula for 6 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="6">your-formula for 6 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="7">your-formula for 6 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="6" y="8">your-formula for 6 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="7" y="1">your-formula for 7 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="2">your-formula for 7 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="3">your-formula for 7 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="4">your-formula for 7 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="5">your-formula for 7 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="6">your-formula for 7 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="7">your-formula for 7 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="7" y="8">your-formula for 7 and 8</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell x="8" y="1">your-formula for 8 and 1</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="2">your-formula for 8 and 2</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="3">your-formula for 8 and 3</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="4">your-formula for 8 and 4</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="5">your-formula for 8 and 5</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="6">your-formula for 8 and 6</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="7">your-formula for 8 and 7</cell>
    <cell x="8" y="8">your-formula for 8 and 8</cell>
  </row>
</matrix>
```

For CSV, there is a sample function called local:csv that creates a text node with the result as follows:

```
 your-formula for 1 and 1,your-formula for 1 and 2,your-formula for 1 and 3,your-formula for 1 and 4,your-formula for 1 and 5,your-formula for 1 and 6,your-formula for 1 and 7,your-formula for 1 and 8
 your-formula for 2 and 1,your-formula for 2 and 2,your-formula for 2 and 3,your-formula for 2 and 4,your-formula for 2 and 5,your-formula for 2 and 6,your-formula for 2 and 7,your-formula for 2 and 8
 your-formula for 3 and 1,your-formula for 3 and 2,your-formula for 3 and 3,your-formula for 3 and 4,your-formula for 3 and 5,your-formula for 3 and 6,your-formula for 3 and 7,your-formula for 3 and 8
 your-formula for 4 and 1,your-formula for 4 and 2,your-formula for 4 and 3,your-formula for 4 and 4,your-formula for 4 and 5,your-formula for 4 and 6,your-formula for 4 and 7,your-formula for 4 and 8
 your-formula for 5 and 1,your-formula for 5 and 2,your-formula for 5 and 3,your-formula for 5 and 4,your-formula for 5 and 5,your-formula for 5 and 6,your-formula for 5 and 7,your-formula for 5 and 8
 your-formula for 6 and 1,your-formula for 6 and 2,your-formula for 6 and 3,your-formula for 6 and 4,your-formula for 6 and 5,your-formula for 6 and 6,your-formula for 6 and 7,your-formula for 6 and 8
 your-formula for 7 and 1,your-formula for 7 and 2,your-formula for 7 and 3,your-formula for 7 and 4,your-formula for 7 and 5,your-formula for 7 and 6,your-formula for 7 and 7,your-formula for 7 and 8
 your-formula for 8 and 1,your-formula for 8 and 2,your-formula for 8 and 3,your-formula for 8 and 4,your-formula for 8 and 5,your-formula for 8 and 6,your-formula for 8 and 7,your-formula for 8 and 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like this.  I'm not certain of what your csv looks like or how your parser loads it.  I have also mocked up some sort of function that you indicated that you have already.

```
declare function local:somefn ($listA as xs:integer*, $listB as xs:integer*) xs:string { "6,7,10,3" };

let $data :=
    <csv>
        <row>1,1,1</row>
        <row>2,2,2</row>
        <row>3,3,3</row>
        <row>4,4,4</row>
    </csv>

for $row1 at $pos in $data/row
for $row2 in $data/row[ position() > $pos ]
    let $x := local:somefn($row1, $row2)
    return $x
```

In baseX this produces:

```
6,7,10,3
6,7,10,3
6,7,10,3
6,7,10,3
6,7,10,3
6,7,10,3
```

Comment: When I run this code i got `your query returned an empty sequence`

Comment: I updated with an example I ran locally.  My xquery engine in baseX so I suppose there might be differences.  I also hard coded what a potential CSV parse might look like in xml.  I get a result.